# How to get the last value of the uneven nested list in python

Tags: python

I read a dynamically changing tree whose value I get in form of a uneven nested list.

```
[u'All VMs & Templates', [[u'vSphere 5.5 (nested)', [[u'Datacenter', [[u'Discovered virtual machine', [u'vm1', 'vm2', 'vm3']]]]]]]
```

The list pattern changes for different tree but in all case I want the last value i.e vm3 here, so is there function or way to get that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a *while* loop to keep fetching last times in each nested list until a non list instance is reached:

```
val = lst[-1]
while isinstance(val, list):
    val = val[-1]
```

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre No need

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre The last while iteration already does that.

Comment: my bad. My code was similar but needed that last stage.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a recursion function as below:

```
In [61]: def get_last(lst):
             last = lst[-1]
             if isinstance(last, list):
                 return get_last(last)
             return last
   ....: 

In [62]: 

In [62]: get_last(lst)
Out[62]: 'vm3'
```

But as a more Pythonic approach, I'd suggest that if you are reading these data from a somewhere else or creating a special type, you can add a particular method for this sake to your object. Something like `preserve_the_last()`. Then, you can use a `deque()` object with maximum length of 1 that accept the input data at each iteration. In this case you'll come up with that latest item at the end. Then you can get the last item using one slicing.